# How to prevent duplicate entries in Gravity Forms within specific dates

Tags: php, wordpress, gravity-forms-plugin, gravityforms

I am trying to prevent duplicate entries for 2 of my Gravity Forms. I need to prevent these entries only within a certain timeframe and based on certain fields like 'email' or 'address'. So if they have an entry with the same 'email' prior to the `start_date`, they can still submit the form without issue. If they have an entry with the same 'email' after the `start_date` and before the `end_date` then they won't be able to submit the form. The code below is what I currently have in place, but it isn't working. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
add_filter( 'gform_is_duplicate', 'custom_duplicate_entry_rules', 10, 4 );
function custom_duplicate_entry_rules( $count, $form_id, $field, $value ) {
  $form_id = array( 6,61 );
  $search_criteria = array(
    'start_date' => 2021-02-01, // Get entries from date after last event 
    'end_date'   => 2022-01-20,   // Up to right before next event
    'field_filters' => array( // which fields to search
      array(
        'key'   => 'email',
      )
    )
  );
  
  $search_past_entries = GFAPI::count_entries($form_id, $search_criteria);
  if ( $search_past_entries >= '1' ) {
    echo 'You have already signed up.';
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I managed to get this figured out with the help of a fellow developer...

```
add_filter( 'gform_is_duplicate_6', 'custom_duplicate_entry_rules', 10, 4 );
add_filter( 'gform_is_duplicate_61', 'custom_duplicate_entry_rules', 10, 4 );
function custom_duplicate_entry_rules( $count, $form_id, $field, $value ) {
  $search_criteria = array(
    'start_date' => '2021-02-01', // Get entries from date after last event 
    'end_date'   => '2022-01-20',   // Up to right before next event
    'field_filters' => array( // which fields to search
      array(
        'key'   => 2,
        'value' => $value,
      )
    )
  );
  $count = GFAPI::count_entries( $form_id, $search_criteria );
  if( $count >= 1 ) {
    return $count;
  } else {
    return 0;
  }
}
```

I needed to zero in on the specific entry meta in `field_filters` which in this case ended up being 2, for the email address (this is the field ID in Gravity Forms). Lastly, I changed the if statement to return `$count` or 0. Gravity Forms does all the heavy lifting beyond that.